# Apply formular if cell in dataframe is not blank in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that is generated by a previous step where the final number of columns added to the dataframe is not known.

For the output dataframe, I want to add a string, "xx", as long as the cell itself is not blank. Here's my sample code:

```
d <- c("a","b","c","")
c <- c("f","","g","h")
e <- data.frame(d,c)

e[] <- lapply(e, function(x) paste("xx", x, sep="_"))
```

In the code above, it would add a "xx" before the blank cell, which is not what I want to do. How do I ensure the formula is only applied when the cell is not blank?

Answer (score 0):

Check first if the cell is empty, e.g., with `nchar`:

```
e[] <- lapply(e, function(x) ifelse(nchar(x) == 0, "", paste("xx", x, sep="_")))
```